# Render updated partial in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a problem updating view with remote: :true

View "do" shows partial: question + answers for this question
It should be updated when button 'Next' clicked, but nothing happens.
I cant imagine why action 'list_update' don't work (In this action i change variable value to display next question + answers for it).

do_controller:

```html
class DoController < ApplicationController
    
    
    def show
        @cur_test = Test.where(id: params[:test_id])
        @cur_q_all = Question.where(test_id: @cur_test)
        @i = 0
        @cur_q = @cur_q_all[@i] 
            
        @cur_ans_all = Answer.where(question_id: @cur_q)
        
    end
    
    def list_update
         @i = 1
          respond_to do |format|
                format.html {}
                format.js {}

            end
    end
end
```

show.html.erb for do_controller:

```html
        <% @cur_test.each do |test| %>
            <div>
                <%= test.test_name %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
            
        
        <div id="answers_all"><%= render('answers_all')%></div>


<%= link_to 'Next', user_test_do_path, method: :get, action: :list_update, remote: :true %>
```

partial _answers_all.erb:

```html
          
            <div>
                <%= @cur_q.q %>
            </div>
            
            <% @cur_ans_all.each do |f| %>
                <div>
                   <%= f.answer %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
```

list_update.js.erb:

```html
$("#answers_all").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("answers_all")) %>");
```

routes:

```html
resources :users do
  resources :tests do
    get '/do' => 'do#show'
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` in the question?

Comment: @Pavan, Yes, done!

Comment: @НикитаЦелищев As per your routes `user_test_do GET    /users/:user_id/tests/:test_id/do(.:format)                      do#show` , you should pass `user_id` and `test_id` to your action.

Comment: @dkp, excuse me, im newbe in rails, if you mean to do that <%= link_to 'Next', user_test_do_path, method: :get, action: :list_update, :user_id => '2', :test_id => '2', remote: :true %>, this didnt change anything

Comment: @НикитаЦелищев please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
<%= link_to 'Next', user_test_do_path(user_id: 1, test_id: 2), method: :get, remote: :true %>`
```

It would hit `do controller's show` action as per your routes.

---

If you want to use `do controller's list_update` action, then you can explicitly mention your `controller` and `action` to be used like below

```
<%= link_to 'Next', {controller: :do, action: :list_update, user_id: 1, test_id: 2}, method: :get, remote: :true %>
```

Add to **routes.rb**

```
get 'do/list_update'
```

Note: In above both scenario, I am passing `user_id` and `test_id` which can be accessed in controller from `params[:user_id]` or `params[:test_id]`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Show action works fine at the start. I want to do the calling of list_update works fine. Understood, but now when link_to updated with controller, user_id, test_id is says that `No route matches {:action=>"list_update", :controller=>"do", :test_id=>2, :user_id=>1}`

Comment: @НикитаЦелищев just add the routes to your `routes.rb` file like `get 'do/list_update'`

Comment: @НикитаЦелищев great !!